# pandoc: converting between .tex and .rst

Tags: pandoc, restructured-text

I'm using `pandoc` to convert from `.tex` to `.rst`.

If I start with the following `.tex` file, `mwe.tex`

### `mwe.tex`

```
\section{Introduction}
Here is some text.

Here is some more text.

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \mycommand{first argument}{second argument}{3rd argument}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    This type of listing is a \texttt{.tex} file.
\end{minipage}%
```

and run the following command

```
pandoc mwe.tex -o mwe.rst
```

then I receive the output

### `mwe.rst`

```
Introduction
============

Here is some text.

Here is some more text.

.4

.4 This type of listing is a ``.tex`` file.
```

I'd like to customize the conversion of the `minipage` environment and `mycommand` command. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc can parse latex macro definitions. This means, that you can add dummy `\newcommand` statements to tweak what will end up in the output:

input file 1: **dummy.tex**

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[3]{(#1) and (#2) and (#3)}
```

input file 2: **mwe.tex**

```
\section{Introduction}
Here is some text.

Here is some more text.

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \mycommand{first argument}{second argument}{3rd argument}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    This type of listing is a \texttt{.tex} file.
\end{minipage}%
```

run:

```
pandoc dummy.tex mwe.tex -o mwe.rst
```

output file **mwe.rst**:

```
Introduction
============

Here is some text.

Here is some more text.

(first argument) and (second argument) and (3rd argument)

.. raw:: latex

   \hfill

This type of listing is a ``.tex`` file.
```

And, as you can see, more recent versions of pandoc (in this case 2.1.1) handle minipages much better.

You might need to write a [filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) for more complicated issues.

Comment: This is great, many thanks indeed; I might follow-up if I have more complicated cases